# how to create a pipe forks two processes

Tags: linux, process, pipe, fork

could anyone help me in understanding what does this question requires?
and the steps to do it?

"Write a simple program that creates a pipe forks two processes and then
sends data through the pipe. Use two standard programs such as (who)
and (wc)."

Comment: `… that creates a pipe, forks two processes and then …` makes lot more sense. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: What programming language are you concerned with here?  It matters, because a shell script could just do `who | wc` and be done with it, while a C program, or a program in some other language, may have to do more plumbing to get it to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You know what a linux pipe is ? If not, read about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inter_process_communication/inter_process_communication_pipes.htm). So, a very basic task is to spawn two processes and connect the output of one task to the input of the other. That is what your question is about.

The question specifies which tasks should be used:

- `who` : list all users currently logged in, one per line.
- `wc`: a small tool to count stuff - words, lines, bytes...

With these two tools, you can easily count the current number of users logged on.

A nice thing about the usual linux tools is that most of them work with stdin - which helps you using pipes, because a linux pipe `|` connects stdout of the process on the left side to the stdin of the process on the right side!

This should help you understand what the question is about...

Answer (score 0):

Read (man) about pipe(int pipefd[2]) syscall - it returns two file descriptors - one for read and one for write. Next fork two processes - you are still in the same (forked process - so you see returned pipefd[] array.

Next if you want to emulate pipe in shell you must

In 1st process:

- close file descriptor 1 (stdout)
- dup() read file descriptor received from pipe() - now it is also fd=1 (stdout)
- exec who

In 2nd process:

- close file descriptor 0 (stdin)
- dup() write file descriptor received from pipe() - now it is also fd=0 (stdin)
- exec wc

Comment: so I have to fork the 'wc' and 'who' processes commands before pipe() them? like I don't clearly know if I can fork an existing  process

Comment: Please read the fork description. The fork create child process for the same program - in parent fork returns with child process id, in child fork returns 0. Based on that values you drive the rest of the code - go on in the paren or spawn in the child (after operations with file descriptors).
If fork return -1 to to the parent - it means error.

Comment: can you please help me how to "exec wc "!    what arguments does exec take and what should I write inside them

Comment: I tried char* args [] = { "wc", "-l", "/full/path/1.text", Null}; 
excuv("/user/bin/wc",args);
but it gives me error

Comment: What error did you get? During compilation or execute? If during execute - check if  return value == -1 and then check the errno value. 
And call is execv, I assume your typing error, is it true?